# change page without post back in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have four pages Map1, Map2, About, Contacts in MVC Project. I want to navigate between Map1 and Map2 without refreshing page so that I can maintain page state while changing page between Map1 and Map2.

Here are my four links for four pages in `_Layout.cshtm`l page of MVC Project.

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Map1", "Index", "map1")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Map2", "Index", "map2")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
```

Comment: Hi, can you share us with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the rationale is to set the internal pages as Partial View, and from the container page (Layout) bring the  Map1, Map2, About, Contacts with Ajax in javascript:

View (layout, but not just):

```
<div id="DestinationLayoutDiv">

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("action", "controller")',
    data: { _param: param},
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#DestinationLayoutDiv').html(data);

    }
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult switchMenu(string param)
    {
        //Your logic, switch or some and return : 

        return PartialView("About");
    }
```